# ObjectQuery.select() method for linq to entities returns error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using entity framework. I have a scenario where I need to select columns of an entity according to user input on run time. I have used following query to select columns dynamically:

```
var query = (ObjectQuery<Users>)entities.Users
var dataRecords = query.Select("it.Name").Distinct();
```

I have followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298787(v=vs.110).aspx) example. This was working fine in production but now suddenly I am getting following error:

> Query builder methods are not supported for LINQ to Entities queries. For more information, see the Entity Framework documentation.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var dataRecords = query.Select("it.Name").Distinct();
```

use:

```
var dataRecords = query.Select(x=>x.Name).Distinct();
```

or

```
var dataRecords = query.Select(x=>new {x.Name}).Distinct();
```

The first will return an `IQueryable<string>`, the second `IQueryable<object>` where the object has a property Name.